# Dramatic performance decrease after switch from local MySQL server to Amazon RDS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I just switched from local MySQL server (on EC2 micro instance) to RDS instance and I see dramatical speed degradation.

One SQL request to RDS equals to 40 requests to local DB.

Large number of SQL requests make script incredibly slow. There is a table, it shows time of website page generation:

**Local MySQL server vs RDS**

```
+----------------------------------+
| Requests | Local server* | RDS*  |
+----------------------------------+
|        1 |           220 |   115 |
|        3 |           200 |    60 |
|       10 |           180 |    25 |
|       20 |           150 |    10 |
|       40 |           115 |     5 |
+----------------------------------+
```

* - Script run speed 1/n, for example 200 means 1/200 sec.

So basically, page with 40 very simple and fast SQL requests, which used to render for 0,008 sec with RDS renders for 0.2 sec, which is significant speed decrease (x23!).

Facts

- EC2 instance and RDS instance are in the same Availability Zone `us-west-1b`
- MySQL Cache enabled (`query_cache_type=1`, `query_cache_size=16777216`, `query_cache_limit=1048576`) and i can see it with `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_type'`
- Queries I run are identical (i just run the same SQL statement multiple times) `select * from user where id = 100`, where `id` is `unique index` and work really fast if exec it using MySQL client (0.0005 sec)
- I use PDO persistent connection

I understand that **there is a network factor** now, RDS it is remote server and there is some latency between client and server but i didn't expect so dramatical decrease, is it normal or there is something i can do with it?

Comment: Its pretty normal. Just the handshake for login can add a ~50ms in my experience. Its one of the more significant tradeoffs your forced to contend with when not having the database on the same server. Also RDS isn't built for sheer performance technically. If you want that you'd need to look at Red Shift.

Comment: are you using PDO persistant connections?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention this. Question updated with this fact.